# Could not load file or assembly 'microsoft.visualstudio.shell.ui.internal' or one of its dependencies. SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

My SQL Server 2012 suddenly stopped working here is all I got in popup message:

could not load file or assembly 'microsoft.visualstudio.shell.ui.internal' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with incorrect format.

[image]

I have Repaired using installation CD but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed by uninstalling the Visual Studio 2010 Shell and installing back. Simply reinstalling doesn't work. 
1. Download the Visual Studio 2010 Shell: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1366
2. Run the exe file and click uninstall(or remove). 
3. Run the exe file and click install with default settings.

After these steps the Management Studio will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in VS2013 when reparing in the logfille,

> [113C:2588][2018-01-20T16:41:54]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (vs_minshellcore) failed: Error Message Id: 1305 ErrorMessage: Error reading from file C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.UI.Internal\v4.0_12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.UI.Internal.dll.  Verify that the file exists and that you can access it.

and I check the file is exist, and I modify its access authority to complete control to every user account, but this error still occur,

Finally I delete this dll, and find same dll in another Normal Computer with VS , and copy the file paste to the problem computer, and run repair again then pass.

Share my works `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.UI.Internal.dll` in [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j4uwcyiys4mfg06/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.UI.Internal.dll?dl=0).

But in my case after repair success, vs2013 still got error when opening, so I finally give up and turn to use vs2015, which luckly can work. It is a strange problem.

Answer (score -1):

have this problem also with vs2019 community. I was trying to create the first 2019 project after it is installed. Then I got this. I ran the install exe file, vs_community.exe again in order to repaire it. But I found out that the install program request to restart the pc to finish the last step. Actually I restarted the pc afterwards manually. But I still did it by clicking on the button "restart pc". After the pc is restarted, the problem is gong. I can create project without any error.